# How would I change Thunderbird's default CSS for links?

Tags: css, email, styles, anchor, thunderbird

I'm trying to change the style for links that are generated when an email is sent from Thunderbird. Specifically, I'm talking about the links that are automatically generated - like email addresses.

Having followed a [tutorial on eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_8239077_change-color-signature-text-thunderbird.html), I have managed to add the style I need in a new `userContent.css` file - however, this does not apply to the message that gets sent; it only applies to what I see in Thunderbird.

This is the style:

```css
a[href] {
    color: #a43335 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

The objective here is to have Thunderbird inject the style into the email that gets sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that this is something that Thunderbird can handle. The reason you can see the link styles when you receive an email in Thunderbird is because Thunderbird is receiving an HTML-formatted email created by another program. Other than some basic styles that Thunderbird provides, it is not a tool for creating full blown HTML emails.

Comment: So, the only way I could achieve this is by manually styling each link in the composer?

Comment: Bingo! Or use web software that was built to send HTML emails like MailChimp.